# Trying to Upgrade a jQM 1.0 Backbone project to 1.3.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, backbone.js

I'm trying to upgrade a Backbone tutorial by **[Steve Smith's](http://stevenpsmith.wordpress.com/2012/02/07/from-a-list-to-a-detail-view-using-jquery-mobile-and-backbone-js/)** jQuery Mobile version from **1.0** to **1.3.1** - the process doesn't seem as straightforward as I first thought however. I get no errors in the console, but nothing "happens." Everything works fine in 1.0 - however when I upgrade the files to 1.3.1, the data isn't rendered.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KraigWalker/MKTqT/1/)

HTML (script imports and css removed):

```
<title>Exercise</title>

<!-- templates -->
<script type="text/template" id="activity-list-item-template">
  <li><a href="#activity-details" identifier="<%= id %>"><%= date %> - <%= type %></a></li>
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="activity-details-template">
    <h3><%= type %></h3>
    <ul data-role="listview" id="activitiy-fields" data-inset="true">
      <li>Date: <%= date %></li>
      <li>Minutes: <%= minutes %></li>
      <li>Distance: <%= distance %></li>
      <li>Comments: <%= comments %></li>
    </ul>
  </script>

<body>

<div data-role="page" id="activities">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Activities</h1>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content">
      <!-- the contents of the list view will be rendered via the backbone view -->
  </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="activity-details" data-add-back-btn="true">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Activity Details</h1>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content" id="activity-details-content">
      <!-- the contents of the list view will be rendered via the backbone view -->
  </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Javascript:

```
var exercise = {};

(function($){

exercise.Activity = Backbone.Model.extend({
});

exercise.Activities = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: exercise.Activity,
    url: "exercise.json",
    comparator: function(activity){
        var date = new Date(activity.get('date'));
        return date.getTime();
    }
});

exercise.ActivityListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'ul',
    id: 'activities-list',
    attributes: {"data-role": 'listview'},

    initialize: function() {
        this.collection.bind('add', this.render, this);
        this.template = _.template($('#activity-list-item-template').html());
    },

    render: function() {
        var container = this.options.viewContainer,
            activities = this.collection,
            template = this.template,
            listView = $(this.el);

        $(this.el).empty();
        activities.each(function(activity){
            var renderedItem = template(activity.toJSON()),
                $renderedItem = $(renderedItem);  //convert the html into an jQuery object
                $renderedItem.jqmData('activityId', activity.get('id'));  //set the data on it for use in the click event
            $renderedItem.bind('click', function(){
                //set the activity id on the page element for use in the details pagebeforeshow event
                $('#activity-details').jqmData('activityId', $(this).jqmData('activityId'));  //'this' represents the element being clicked
            });
            listView.append($renderedItem);
        });
        container.html($(this.el));
        container.trigger('create');
        return this;
    }
});

exercise.ActivityDetailsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    //since this template will render inside a div, we don't need to specify a tagname
    initialize: function() {
        this.template = _.template($('#activity-details-template').html());
    },

    render: function() {
        var container = this.options.viewContainer,
            activity = this.model,
            renderedContent = this.template(this.model.toJSON());

        container.html(renderedContent);
        container.trigger('create');
        return this;
    }
});

exercise.initData = function(){
    exercise.activities = new exercise.Activities();
    exercise.activities.fetch({async: false});  // use async false to have the app wait for data before rendering the list
};

}(jQuery));

$('#activities').on('pageinit', function(event){
var activitiesListContainer = $('#activities').find(":jqmData(role='content')"),
    activitiesListView;
exercise.initData();
activitiesListView = new exercise.ActivityListView({collection: exercise.activities, viewContainer: activitiesListContainer});
activitiesListView.render();
});

$('#activity-details').on('pagebeforeshow', function(){
    console.log('activityId: ' + $('#activity-details').jqmData('activityId'));
    var activitiesDetailsContainer = $('#activity-details').find(":jqmData(role='content')"),
        activityDetailsView,
        activityId = $('#activity-details').jqmData('activityId'),
    activityModel = exercise.activities.get(activityId);

    activityDetailsView = new exercise.ActivityDetailsView({model: activityModel, viewContainer: activitiesDetailsContainer});
    activityDetailsView.render();
});
```

This seems to be an issue that's scuppered a few people. 1.3.0 makes things like the parameter  passing plugin break, so there must have been a change in the networking code somewhere.

Comment: Don't know if this is of any help, but I once "upgraded" another jQM & Backbone tutorial like this: https://github.com/ccoenraets/backbone-jquerymobile/pull/3

Comment: Thanks, will check this out and get back to you

Comment: So I've had a dig around his code and the tutorial and it looks like he's doing a different approach. I did however change .live to .on in advance. It seems like the tutorial you linked to dynamically creates and destroys the pages, while my app changes the contents of the pages in the render() function

Comment: Looking at your fiddle I *do* get console errors by the way: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'each' of undefined` @ `backbone-min.js:1` and `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'extend' of undefined`

Comment: Think they had been imported incorrectly into the fiddle. That issue looks to be fixed...

Comment: [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KraigWalker/MKTqT/1/)

Comment: I've looked at the eventlog closely and it doesn't seem like anything's really firing. I've taken it out of it's **(function($){** and still nothing really happened (I don't know what I was expecting) - are there different events in jQM 1.0 from 1.3??

Comment: One trouble (at least with your fiddle) should be that you need to bind the `mobileinit` before you load the jQM source, otherwise the handler won't fire anymore when bound after jQM has been loaded. See: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/globalconfig.html

Comment: That's a stroke of good thinking there! In my project I've changed the order I load the script files so that jQuery loads first, then backbone and underscore, and **then** my app code before jQM. I've been reading through the JQM section of the [O'Reilly Developing Backbone.js Apps](http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/#mobile-app-development-with-jquery-mobile) and it doesn't seem to be aware of this (the book seems to be only half up-to-date, using jQM 1.0 in examples but referring to 1.3 doc links) I'm going to set out disabling some of jQM's nav stuff like in ccoenraets e.g.

Comment: Hey guys. Managed to fix the issue by implementing a router. Will post the solution when I have the time